# Java multi-line regular expression debugging

Tags: java, regex, multiline

In Java, the following regular expression

```
To: a@b\.com.*Subject: Please verify your email address
```

somehow doesn't find the match in this text:

```
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: High Replication
    Storage: In-memory
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO: MailService.send
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   From: 
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   To: a@b.com
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Subject: Please verify your email address
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Body:
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:     Content-type: text/plain
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:     Data length: 4
```

My Java code looks like this:

```java
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        ...
    }
```

This is a bit strange, since the pattern seems to work when I test it online with this tool: http://regexpal.com

So, Java must be interpreting the pattern a bit differently. Is there any way to get error messages of the `Matcher`?

**Update** It should find:

```
To: a@b.com
Dez 21, 2012 10:29:58 AM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Subject: Please verify your email address
```

Comment: Well, I can't find any text related to that regex in your shown input text.

Comment: @RohitJain there is a match inside the text. I updated my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) instead of [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE).

`DOTALL` makes the `.` match newlines. (Which is what you want)

`MULTILINE` makes `^` and `$` work on a per-line basis.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was missing. Thank you.